# How to get the coordinates of the point that I click?

Tags: css, canvas

I am playing with `<canvas>` tag and just encountered a problem:

https://jsfiddle.net/awguo/6yLqa5hz/

I want to get the coordinates of a point when I click on a canvas.

I searched for a while and found some functions, but as a 300x300 canvas, the point of its right-bottom point is (300,150). Shouldn't it be 300,300 (because the img is 300x300 and the canvas is 100% on it)?

Why?

What should I do to get the `300x300`?

Comment: Why are you making that substraction ??? the canvas size is 350x350 therefore the img is 350x350 https://jsfiddle.net/6yLqa5hz/1/ bottom right must be 350,350

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must adjust the `event.clientX` and `event.clientY` coordinates returned by your event handlers by the offset of the canvas element vs the window. To do that you can use `canvas.getBoundingClientRect` to get the `left` & `top` canvas offsets. Be sure to listen for `resize` & `scroll` events. When those events happen you must re-fetch the canvas's current offset.

```
// Fetch offsetX & offsetY variables that contain the 
// canvas offset versus the window
// Re-fetch when the window is resized or scrolled
function reOffset(){
    var BB=canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    offsetX=BB.left;
    offsetY=BB.top;        
}
var offsetX,offsetY;
reOffset();
window.onscroll=function(e){ reOffset(); }
window.onresize=function(e){ reOffset(); }
```

Here's how to use the offsets to calculate correct mouse coordinates in an event handler:

```
function handleMouseDown(e){

    // tell the browser we're handling this event
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

    // calculate the mouse position
    mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
    mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

    // your stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function getMousePos(canvas, evt) {
  var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  return {
    x: evt.clientX,
    y: evt.clientY
  };
}
```

Is enough to work. You image is 350px big, not 300px.